# listview shows nothing and hide data

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview

i want to show seven textviews and two buttons horizontally in list. My list works fine with five textviews if a add more controls then it does not show anything. my code is correct i tried to change everything in xml but i'm unable to see anything  on screen. please help me how can i use it in correct format.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

 <!-- Third header line and column headings -->
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#A1E9FF">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/column_header1"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/column_header2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
 </LinearLayout>  

 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:divider="#b5b5b5"
    android:dividerHeight="2dp">
</ListView>
```

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="horizontal" >

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/plan_date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Plan_no"
    android:text="plan date "
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/morn_even"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/doc_code"
    android:text="morn_even"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
    android:text="Visited"
    android:textColor="#000" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ff_code"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/morn_even"
    android:text="ff code"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/speciality"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ff_code"
    android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ff_code"
    android:text="speciality"
     android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="15dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/plan_date"
    android:text="mon"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Plan_no"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
    android:text="plan no"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/doc_code"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mon"
    android:text="doc_code"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="Not Visited"
    android:textColor="#000" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your problem could be because you're trying to show more items than there is space in the screen. To counter this effect you could use an [HorizontalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html) which let's you scroll horizontaly to see all the Views.

Also the orientation attribute won't work on RelativeLayout, I'd suggest you use [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/plan_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Plan_no"
        android:text="plan date "
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/morn_even"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/doc_code"
        android:text="morn_even"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
        android:text="Visited"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ff_code"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/morn_even"
        android:text="ff code"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/speciality"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ff_code"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ff_code"
        android:text="speciality"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="15dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/plan_date"
        android:text="mon"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Plan_no"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
        android:text="plan no"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/doc_code"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mon"
        android:text="doc_code"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Not Visited"
        android:textColor="#000" />

</LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

PS: I was to lazy to remove the RelativeLayout specific attributes eg: alignTop, alignParentRight etc. So feel free to remove those.

Comment: i appreciate your code. but torque203 it did not worked for me. i tried it for both horizontally and vertically but i still gets the empty screen.

Answer (score 5):

As Torque203 noted, the `orientation` attribute is not valid for a `RelativeLayout`.

Another reason your `RelativeLayout` has not worked as you intended is that ***order matters*** when you define the relative positions of your child views.
When a `RelativeLayout` is inflated the XML is read from top to bottom, and a new child view can only be specified as relative to other child views that have already been defined before it.

Consider your second TextView:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/morn_even"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/doc_code"
    android:text="morn_even"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="15dp" />
```

You specify that this view is "toRightOf" the view `doc_code`, but the `RelativeLayout` doesn't know anything about this `doc_code` view yet, because you don't define it until near the end of the XML.

Your are not alone here though. A lot of people misunderstand this when they first start playing with `RelativeLayout`.

The key thing to understand is that a `RelativeLayout` will only implement relative position rules that are anchored to a view who's position is already defined and fixed.

For example consider a new empty `RelativeLayout`:

- We add a new child view `A` to it.

For this first child, we can only specify position rules relative to it's parent.
If we don't define any position rules relative to it's parent, it will be placed in the top left corner by default.

- We add a new child view `B`.

For this child we can specify position rules relative to it's parent or relative to the existing view `A`.
We cannot specify any position rules relative to view `C` which hasn't been defined yet.

In a real world example, say I was lining up people for a group photo and first I tell Jim to stand at the center of the shot. If I then say "Ok Anita, you stand to the right of Liz" you are either just going to look at me funny, or say "But I don't know where Liz is meant to be standing yet!".